# Collapse all UI folders

Tags: interface, startup-file

Here is a lot of expanded UI folders I want to collapse and save the startup file, because I don't like them to be expanded.

[image]

But I don't want to do it manually. Does anyone know the way to do it recursively without manual collapsing each of this folders?

Comment: It's a bit tricky but you can click on the top folder header to collapse it, keep the mouse button pressed and move your mouse down to collapse all the other ones. It still requires user movement but only 1 click

Comment: OMG! It's working much faster. But it doesn't do the job. It doesn't collapse recursively. Maybe there is any options in settings, to keep them collapsed by default?

Comment: Oh right, then the shortcut is CTRL + Click :)

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot! Maybe you also know some option in preferences, or somewhere else to make all folders collapsed by default in one click? Or this option wasn't developed yet?

Comment: [Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/window_system/tabs_panels.html)